# Degree of dual variety of complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complete intersection in $\mathbb P^n$, does anyone know how to calculate the degree of a dual variety of $X$?

Some preliminaries can be found in [3264 and all that](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/joeharris/files/000-final-3264.pdf), chapter 10. For instance, such dual varieties are always codimension one (except when $X$ is linear); and when $X$ is a hypersurface, the answer is well know.

In particular, I'd like to know the answer when $X$ is the curve as a complete intersection by a cubic and quadric in $\mathbb P^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a smooth complete intersection of type $(d_1,\dots,d_k)$ in $\mathbb{P}(V)$. Consider the bundle
$$
E := \bigoplus \mathcal{O}_X(1 - d_i) \hookrightarrow V^\vee \otimes \mathcal{O}_X,
$$
where the morphism is given by the derivatives of the equations of $X$. Then $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is the universal tangent hyperplane to $X$, hence the dual variety is the image of the map
$$
\mathbb{P}_X(E) \to \mathbb{P}(V^\vee)
$$
induced by the embedding $E \to V^\vee \otimes \mathcal{O}_X$. Therefore, the degree of the dual variety is 
$$
\deg(X^\vee) = s_{n}(E),
$$ 
where $n = \dim(X)$ and $s_n$ is the $n$-th Segre class (this is true under the assumption that the map $\mathbb{P}_X(E) \to X^\vee$ is birational, otherwise you need to divide by its degree). This class is easy to compute: this is the coefficient of $h^n$ in
$$
\left(\prod_{i=1}^k(1 - (d_i - 1)h)^{-1}\right)\prod_{i=1}^k d_i.
$$

In the case of a $(2,3)$ intersection in $\mathbb{P}^3$ this gives $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 18$.

Comment: Dear Sasha, thanks for your elegant answer. The formula you provided is exactly what I was looking for. However, I still don't understand why $\deg(X^{\vee})$ is the $n$-th Segre class (The only thing that I know about $s_*(E)$ is the total Segre class is the inverse of the total Chern class). Is there a way to relate $s_n(E)$ with the fact that the degree of the dual variety is the number of points of intersection of $X^{\vee}$ by a general line in $\mathbb P(V^{\vee})$?

Comment: The important thing is that $s_n(E)$ is equal to the top self-intersection of the relative hyperplane class of $\mathbb{P}_X(E)$, see Fulton, Intersection Theory, Section 3.1.

Comment: Dear Sasha, I always find your comments/solutions informative and illuminating. If you are available, could you have a look of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3728109/why-the-exceptional-divisor-of-blowup-of-x2yt-0-has-multiplicity-one-bu) about multiplicity on the exceptional divisor? I have been puzzled about it for a long time and I would greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the $h^n$ in the explanation should be $h^{n-k}$. E.g. in the case $k=n$ the expression in the parentheses must be equal to $1$.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I took the liberty of adding mathematical formatting to your answer.

Comment: Hello Herb, thanks for your comment, but I think according to Sasha's notation, $n$ is the dimension of $X$, instead of the dimension of the ambient projective space, so the formula should be correct.